# Moshi Request Body Polymorphic Serialization Issue [From GSON to MOSHI]

Tags: kotlin, gson, retrofit, moshi

I have a question regarding Moshi Polymorphic serialization and I didn't find any proper answer anywhere.

I have an API (Update User) that takes different parameters that I want to update.
E.g. {firstName, lastName}, {phoneNumber}, {email} etc.

I was originally using `GSON` as my converter Lib and I had this structure.

```
interface UpdateUserParams

data class UpdateName(
   val firstName : String,
   val lastName : String) : UpdateUserParams

data class UpdateEmail(
   val email : String) : UpdateUserParams

data class UpdatePhoneNumber(
   val phoneNumber : String) : UpdateUserParams


@POST("URL")
fun updateUser(@Body params : UpdateUserParams)
```

And I was using GSON Serialization to serialize `UpdateUserParams`
Now I am working on updating from `GSON` to `Moshi` and I am running into the issues. I tried using the Polymorphic serialization but that is also passing the additional field which I don't want.

```
enum class UpdateUserType{
    NAME,
    EMAIL,
    PHONE
}

sealed class UpdateUserParams()

val updateUserAdapterFactory: PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory<UpdateUserParams> =
    PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(UpdateUserParams::class.java, "type")
        .withSubtype(UpdateName::class.java, UpdateUserType.NAME.name)
        .withSubtype(UpdateEmail::class.java, UpdateUserType.EMAIL.name)
        .withSubtype(UpdatePhoneNumber::class.java, UpdateUserType.PHONE.name)


data class UpdateName(
   val firstName : String,
   val lastName : String) : UpdateUserParams

data class UpdateEmail(
   val email : String) : UpdateUserParams

data class UpdatePhoneNumber(
   val phoneNumber : String) : UpdateUserParams
```

But the problem here is the final `requestBody` looks like this.

```
{firstName : "Alex", lastName : "Anderson", type : "Name"}
```

How do I remove `type` from the Request Body?

Comment: Your question is not fully clear and I don't really get it: you're saying that you're migrating from Gson to Moshi, but you're not saying if you used `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` before, a Gson counter-part to Moshi `PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory`. Both of them are used for serialization and deserialization and they both use the discriminator field (i.e. `type`) to deserialize. If you didn't use `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`, then you probably don't need `PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory` at all, thus both Gson and Moshi can do that easily. I mean, isn't `UpdateUserParams` simply a marker interface?

Comment: @fluffy I was not using the `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`. I was using `JsonSerializer` to serialize `UpdateUserParams` interface. So I guess my question is how do I serialize an `interface` in `Moshi` so that I can pass any child data class as Body param to the API.